# searching for a pattern and printing the output on console

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

Input file looks like this:

```
{"key":"value";"ipaddress:"scrubbed";"id":"scrubbed"}
{"key1":"value";"ipaddress:"scrubbed";"id":"scrubbed"}
{"key2":"value";"ipaddress:"scrubbed";"id":"scrubbed"}
{"key3":"value";"ipaddress:"scrubbed";"id":"scrubbed"}
```

scenario:

i have to check whether ip address and id got scrubbed or not for all input lines in above file

excepted output to be printed on console:

```
ip address and id got scrubbed in all the lines of input file
```

Comment: I tried to clean up the quotations in your input, but there doesn't seem to be a pattern behind it.

Comment: Welcome to Unix and Linux, we're happy to help and offer suggestions if you are having trouble with something, but this forum is geared towards learning, rather than a script writing service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can there be more than two appearances of "scrubbed" in any given line? Can the value be "scrubbed"? Also, seems like the closing quotes after ipaddress are missing.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the value "scrubbed" can appear only against id and ipaddress. May not be the best solution though.

```
#!/bin/bash

flag=0

while read -r line
do
    if [[ $(echo "$line" | grep -o -w scrubbed | wc -l) -ne 2 ]]
    then
        echo 'IP address and id NOT scrubbed in every line!'
        echo "$line"
        flag=1
        break
    fi
done < input.txt

if [[ $flag -ne 1 ]]
then
    echo 'ip address and id got scrubbed in all the lines of input file'
fi
```

Note: `grep -o` [prints all matches in a given line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15366097/147021).